# Request payment part way through course

Tags: paypal, payment, moodle

I'd like students to be able to access the first couple of lessons in Moodle before being presented with a request for payment. I've searched for ages on Google and found nothing, and also searched for all the possible terms I could think of here, and again come up short. Apologies therefore for the lack of contributing research/evidence.

I'm using Paypal as the chosen method of payment at the moment. Moodle is version 3.2.

Is there a way to add this kind of option to the 'access restrictions' in the courses themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an existing way to restrict activity access based on the users enrolment type.

Without writing some custom code, the easiest way to do this is probably to have a separate course containing the pay-walled content, with paypal enrolment set up.

Add an activity to the free course with a link to the paid course. Use access restrictions to hide it until the other activities are complete.

When a user completes the free course content, the link to the paid course will be revealed, and they can click to enrol using paypal.